# what is the SQL 2005 version that i can install on Win XP?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

what is the SQL 2005 version that i can install on Win XP ?

I need DataBase and to create tables,query....

thank's in advance

Answer (score 3):

Best option is probably SQL Server Express.  http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=220549b5-0b07-4448-8848-dcc397514b41&displaylang=en

The express editions provide a lightweight version of SQL server that will work for most standalone applications, and smaller web projects.

Answer (score 1):

Either [SQL Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/Express.aspx) or [SQL Compact edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx). In most situations you will use SQL Express edition.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with SQL Express or SQL Compact Edition, the use thos.  But if you need the extra features and you're planning on using XP for development and then using server 2003 or 2008 for deployment, [SQL Server Development edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/developer.aspx) can be installed on XP for development purposes.  This gives you access to all the Enterprise features for a much lower price during development.